# How to use iFrame in multiple galleries with iziModal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

[iziModal official](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/)
As in the official sample, make iFrame if I press a button
...Not, I want to make iFrame appear when I press `section`.
I would like to have details displayed in the modal window when I push the collection of works.

### Like this

[image: push]

⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎

[image: &iframe!]

---

### Below, my immovable code

jQuery, izimodal.css, izimodal.js are properly included.
(The content of iFrame is the html file that I have.)

HTML

```
<div class="list">
<div class="items">
 <section class="item item1" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-1.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/1.png" alt="1" />
   <h2>title1</h2>
   <p>description1 description1</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item2" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-2.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/2.png" alt="2" />
   <h2>title2</h2>
   <p>description2 description2</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item3" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-3.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/3.png" alt="3" />
   <h2>title3</h2>
   <p>description3 description3</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item4" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-4.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/4.png" alt="4" />
   <h2>title4</h2>
   <p>description4 description4</p>
 </section>
 <section class="item item5" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-5.html" data-izimodal-open=#iframe>
   <img src="img/5.png" alt="5" />
   <h2>title5</h2>
   <p>description5 description5</p>
 </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
// In case of item1
$(document).on('click', '.item1', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#iframe').iziModal('open');
});
  $("#iframe").iziModal({
  iframe: true,
  width: '98%',
  ifremeHeight: '98%',
  zindex: '10',
  iframeURL: "data-1.html",
  group: 'works',
  overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
});
```

How do I activate iziModal & make multiple iFrames?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, first, you need to pass new URL from the HTML like below:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="items">
        <section class="item item1" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-1.html" data-izimodal-open="#iframe" data-href="/iframe_url1">
            <img src="img/1.png" alt="1" />
            <h2>title1</h2>
            <p>description1 description1</p>
        </section>
        <section class="item item2" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-2.html" data-izimodal-open="#iframe" data-href="/iframe_url2">
            <img src="img/2.png" alt="2" />
            <h2>title2</h2>
            <p>description2 description2</p>
        </section>
        <section class="item item3" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-3.html" data-izimodal-open="#iframe" data-href="/iframe_url3">
            <img src="img/3.png" alt="3" />
            <h2>title3</h2>
            <p>description3 description3</p>
        </section>
        <section class="item item4" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-4.html" data-izimodal-open="#iframe" data-href="/iframe_url4">
            <img src="img/4.png" alt="4" />
            <h2>title4</h2>
            <p>description4 description4</p>
        </section>
        <section class="item item5" data-izimodal-iframeurl="data-5.html" data-izimodal-open="#iframe" data-href="/iframe_url5">
            <img src="img/5.png" alt="5" />
            <h2>title5</h2>
            <p>description5 description5</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change the Javascript part to change the iframe url:

```
// CHANGE THE URL
    $('#iframe').iziModal('open',{
        iframeURL: $this.data('href')
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!
First of all, since iFrame can not be opened, I couldn't confirm it, but does `data-href` mean that I should write as it is?
Or is it to apply `data-1.html` to `iframe_url1`? I still don't understand JS yet.. I'm sorry.

Comment: I just wrote data-href so you can open send the ifram url to the click function can get it but you can write whatever you want

Comment: I see! I can put in the iFrameURL that I want to open For example, I should put "data-1.html" now, don't I?
I'll respond again when I can open iFrame in iziModal. If you don't mind, I would be happy if you tell me why my iziModal doesn't react.